# django-tables2 exclude not working SingleTableMixin

Tags: django, django-tables2

Using SingleTableMixin, nothing but the model is being passed to the rendered table. I commented out every line until it broke and **model = Stat is the only thing required for it to work.

I saw similar questions but nothing particular to my case since the table is rendering, just without any of the class Meta info except model

```
tables.py

class StatTable(tables.Table):

class Meta:
    model = Stat
    data = Stat.objects.all()
    exclude = ('id',)
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover table-condensed'}

views.py

class StatTableMixin(SingleTableMixin):
    table_class = StatTable
    context_table_name = 'stat_table'

class AircraftList(ListView, StatTableMixin):
    model = Aircraft
    template_name = "aircraft/aircraft_list.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AircraftList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = "D-> | Aircraft"
    context['stat_table'] = Stat.objects.all()
    return context
```

Comment: `data` is not a valid attribute for `Table.Meta`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a custom `context_table_name`, and assign a `QuerySet` (`Stat.objects.all()`) to that name in `get_context_data()`. This will make django-tables2 render the default view for a `queryset`, not the custom one you want (`StatTable`).

You can fix this by not assigning the queryset to `context['stat_table']` and using [`ListView.get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) to prepare the correct queryset to populate the table with data.